# Delphi - Excel - Adding Shadows to Shapes

Tags: excel, delphi

I have an Excel spreadsheet which has a known series of pictures.  I need to add a shadow (property called SoftEdge) to these pictures. While the VBA code to do this is easy (Captured via Macro recording), I am unable to get the Delphi equivalent to work.  I loop through each picture, get a handle to the picture, and then set the SoftEdge type.  I know my handle is valid, because I can 'MyExcelPic.Delete' and that works. I have tried defining MyExcelPic as both OleVariant and Shape.  When defined as Shape, I get an AV, when defined as OleVariant, I get 'type_ not supported by automation object'.

Here is the relevant snippet of code...

```
var
MyExcelPic:  Shape;
begin
...
  for i := 1 to TotalPicCount do
  begin
     // VBA Code...
    //ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 13")).Select
    //Selection.ShapeRange.SoftEdge.Type = msoSoftEdgeType1

    MyExcelPic := ExcelCloudSheet.Shapes.Item('Picture ' + IntToStr(i));
    //MyExcelPic.Delete;
    MyExcelPic.SoftEdge.type_ :=  msoSoftEdgeType1;
  end;
```

The only oddity I see is that the Excel Macro defines 'type', while Delphi defines 'type_'.  In a perfect world, I would like a range of all shapes on the sheet, and set the SoftEdge property in one pass, but at this point, any way of setting this property is great...

Comment: I tend to use Variant rather than OLEVariant, but I guess either would work. You can't use Shape, and don't need the underscore;

Comment: If you add a [MCVE] then I should be able to use it to post an answer.

Comment: Using Variant seemed to work.  I also switched from SoftEdge to Shadow.  Working now...  Submit as answer and I will accept.

Comment: "The only oddity I see is that ...":  The reason for that is that Delphi changes member names of the Excel objects to avoid clashes with Delphi reserved words, etc, like `type` by adding an underscore.  It's just so that the type library import unit is compilable, and makes no diffference to the compiled code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Variant rather than OLEVariant. You can't use Shape, and don't need the underscore. You pointed out that you switched to shadow, but I don't think that is relevant to the question.

Using your code this would equate to the following

```
var
MyExcelPic:  Variant;
begin
...
  for i := 1 to TotalPicCount do
  begin
     // VBA Code...
    //ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 13")).Select
    //Selection.ShapeRange.SoftEdge.Type = msoSoftEdgeType1

    MyExcelPic := ExcelCloudSheet.Shapes.Item('Picture ' + IntToStr(i));
    //MyExcelPic.Delete;
    MyExcelPic.SoftEdge.type :=  msoSoftEdgeType1;
  end;
```